# Would it be permissible to do mashaa on the wig when redoing wahdu if the wig was worn in wahdu?

Tags: sharia, practical-islam, wudu

I have alopecia, my hair has fallen.

So I was wondering if I could do the mashah while doing wahdu, if I ready have a valid wadhu, while wearing the wig? Similar to washing feet and wearing socks.

Answer (score 1):

**It would be a valid Wudhu if you cannot pick it up (you cannot remove your wig). Hence you can Mash on it.**

( in accordance with the ruling of Grand Ayatollah Hadawi Tehrani as a Marja’ al Taqlid of Shia)

But I recommend you to read the site blow which consists of more detailed info. Regarding the mentioned issue. (Of course I could not find it in English), Anyhow, I hope at least you could find your matter in one of these three languages)

**Source**:

http://islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa21348 (in Arabic)

http://islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa21348 (in Farsi)

http://islamquest.net/tr/archive/question/fa21348 (in Turkish)